# Photoshop, копирование цвета в hex

Tags: javascript, photoshop

В фотошопе, если выбрать слой текста, и потом правой кнопкой вызвать меню и выбрать "Копировать CSS", то цвет копируется в формате rgb.
Подскажите, как настроить фотошоп, чтобы цвет копировался в hex?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего нет такой опции. Можете попробовать этот плагин:

http://css3ps.com

Сам я его не пробовал, но судя по генерируемому коду цвет там в hex-формате (если нет прозрачности).

Comment: скорее всего можно это сделать через js-скрипт.